# Install 14.04 via lan

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lan

I have a old machine(pc) which doesn't contain os in it. (I can't boot it from pendrive or cd).

I want to install 14.04 over the local network on this device, as a server I could use a modern laptop with ubuntu gnome 14.04 I have.

I don't want to install ubuntu over the internet as it consumes my bandwidth :(

Can some say me how to do it with the iso i have in my modern computer in detail

I have tried to read the documentation of the Ubuntu but could not figure it on my own.

Comment: Please note that it doesn't contain any use in it, I can access only bios

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download one of the installation ISO's, loop-back mount it, and serve it with a local HTTP/FTP server.

This will only work if you can boot the machine with a CD or USB, so no luck for you.

You could use a PXE installation, but that's non-trivial. If you don't know how to setup and configure DHCP/BOOTP, TFTP, and FTP/HTTP, look for other options.

Anyway, both methods are described in the source.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet)

Comment: If you can't boot the old machine via CD or USB stick, then you can't use the ISO method. You can still use PXE though, but it's non-trivial.

Comment: do you have any other source which gives us more details of this procedure , as I am not getting it exactly

Comment: The source is so exhausting and complete, I beleive you won't find any better.

Comment: I am not able to understand all the terms in it :( , i will ask some one in person help :)

Comment: Denis Waitley  
"View life as a continuous learning experience."

Comment: ya my pholosopy is every person is a student till he dies :) 
hope one day I could do it myself :)